# calling method in static generic class without specifying type

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods, static

Consider the following code, I want to do something like this, **this doesn't work but this is what I want**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass.Test("something");
    }
}

public static class TestClass<T>
{
    public static void Test(T something) { }
}
```

The code below will work but I have like 20 generic methods in the same class and they are repeating their constraints over and over again.

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test<T>(T something) { }
}
```

I don't want to do this because I don't want the people who use my code specifies string as the type, because "something" is already a string

```
 TestClass<string>.Test("something");
```

To explain my question in another way round, I want to pull the same generic type and constraints from like 20 methods in the same class, I don't want them to repeat over and over, and I don't want user to specify the type when they use my methods, the parameter they pass in will supply the type.

Thanks!

Comment: your code works fine, compiler will infer the type

Comment: @EhsanSajjad [Are you sure?](http://rextester.com/CFOGL63087) `Using the generic type 'Rextester.TestClass<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: Are all the types that might be passed in `TestClass<string>.Test("something");` call, known to you?

Comment: Why are you unable to move the type parameter off of the class and down to the methods?

Comment: @DavidB there are like 20 methods that uses the following generic type, am I supposed to rewrite it 20 times just to make the method caller no need to specify type? If I change the constraint I need to change 20 times?

Comment: @LeeSong sure, the .net framework does that (System.Linq.Enumerable.Enumerable)

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the generic on the class itself, you need to specify it, as you noted in your question - this would work:

```
TestClass<string>.Test("something")
```

If you want the compiler to infer it, you need to put it on the method instead:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test<T>(T something) { }
}

TestClass.Test("something");// T is infered.
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/VOF10456

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need this:

```
public static void Test<T>(T myValue) {. ..}
```

Then call it like this:

```
TestClass.Test("DoSomething");
```

Which will automatically infer the type `string` for you, you won´t need to specify it within the type-parameter.